# How can I use the values of a GDB coded value domain in QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, expression, domains

In a GDB the attribute `size` contains a coded value domain `{0: small, 1:medium, 2: big}`.
How can I access the value of a domain of a GDB in QGIS? I want to use the value in an expression or a field calculator.

Answer (score 1):

The function  `represent_value` can be used in a QGIS expression to access the value of a coded value domain.
For example:

```
represent_value( "size" )
```

will return the value.